# Batch file uploading to cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Could anyone cut and paste a working request to upload several files to cloud storage in a batch.  I am really struggling to get it working, there are no examples of file uploads and I'm really stuck.  Could probably work it out if I had a working starting point.  I'm starting to go crazy so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What language and client library are you using?

Comment: When you say batch uploading, do you mean that you want to upload many files with a single HTTP connection? Or do you just want to upload many files period?

Comment: Also, if you just want the files uploaded period, does this necessarily need to use a client library? If not, note that gsutil (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) handles uploaded large numbers of files for you in parallel.

Comment: I am not using a client library because the PHP library does not work when batching uploads together.  It's a bug.

Comment: I am trying to upload multiple files in a single request.  This should be possible because it's mentioned in the documentation but I can't figure it out through trial and error.

Comment: Seems even google support are stumped with this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example at [1] and consult this other answer at [2] as reference.

I would suggest you to use gsutil to copy files even as an external call from your application (PHP exec() or system()) since this tool is optimised for parallel file transfer (-m option) and recursive folder copy (-R option) making it very simple and efficient.

For more help on gsutil copy command : gsutil cp help

Links:
[1] - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch#example
[2] - [Batch upload requests to Google Cloud Storage using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746363/batch-upload-requests-to-google-cloud-storage-using-javascript)

Regards
Paolo

Comment: I'm already using the gsutil command but there are a few issues.  The apache user has to be logged in to gsutil and responses have to be parsed as strings etc.  Error handling is tricky.  From my tests I've found it to be a bit of a wonky solution.

Comment: Regarding the two links, thanks but I've already read them both extensively.  I have had no luck using either endpoints specified in the javascript one and the documentation of json api does not deal with file uploading.  I suspect due to the fact that the api endpoint is different.  I am in discussions with google cloud support to get a working copy of a request which I can adapt.

Comment: On [1] I found this text  "Note: Currently, Google Cloud Storage does not support batch operations for media, either for upload or download." which makes it unusable for batch uploads